# How to store a matched regular expression as a string in a variable

Tags: ruby, regex, expression

Does anyone know how to take a matched regular expression as a string and store it in  a variable? If my string is `"police"` and my regex matches it to get the result as `"ice"`, how could I store `"ice"` in a variable? My guesses are the `match`, `scan` and `to_s` methods.

I plan to use the stored string (using regex) to pass to a :prefix option in a tree interface method of the `aws-sdk` in RAILS to interact with aws-s3 objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to use regular expressions in Ruby. Using the `match` operator, you get a MatchData object, which can be turned into a String with the `to_s` method. If your regex doesn't match, you'll get nil instead of a MatchData object.

```
my_match = /ice/.match("police");
my_var = my_match.to_s;
```

Or just do it all at once. If the regex doesn't match, you'll get an empty string.

```
my_var = /ice/.match("police").to_s;
```

Comment: If you are going to ding me, tell me why. I can learn something.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, This works. I just realized that the problem Im facing is not with the regular expression. Heres the issue  Im trying to pass a parameter (a file path : eg. user/lauren/tools/) from a view in RAILS to another controller. I want to use the file path (as a string) to be matched with the regular expression. To do that, right now Im using the params [:parameter] method as follows   in the controller action where im setting the variable instance:     @variable = /^.+\/[^\/]+$/.match(params[:name]).to_s                   Id appreciate your views on this...thanks!

Comment: If the file path ends with a '/', as it does in your example, the regex ^.+\/[^\/]+$ won't match. If you add \/ to the end, it'll match that ending '/'. If you make it optional, you'll get a match either with or without the ending '/'. Here's the regex that allows an optional trailing slash.  ^.+\/[^\/]+[\/]*$

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of choices, but:

```
my_variable = /ice/.match("police")[0]
```

will assign the matched expression to `my_variable`